Selenium webdriver handle prompt window or setup a proxy with authentication
prompt window
I found 3 ways to setup a proxy for Selenium WebDriver:

Pass as an argument like:
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://104.239.10.110:5781");
Create a Proxy object:

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

        // Set proxy authentication
        String proxyAuth = proxyUsername + ":" + proxyPassword;
        proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

        chromeOptions.setProxy(proxy);


Create the extension and import it

2 and 3 aren't working for me (no idea why). 1 is working but there is no option to setup username and password. So the questions are:

Is there any way to setup a username+password?
Chrome asks for a login and pass in a prompt window. Anybody know how to pass arguments there? In the documentation i found that i should handle it as an alert window but it also not works - no such alert error

Already tried all ways to setup a proxy with authentication.
Already tried to handle prompt window due to the documentation

Did you solve this issue? If yes, could you share your solution.
